# DLP projector instant off disadvantages

Tags: lamp, projector

My projector (Acer H6520BD) has an instant off setting. When it is turned on the projector turns off instantly when I press power off. If the instant off setting is turned off, the projector remains active for a few dozens of seconds. During this time the lamp is glowing dimly and I hear the fan going.

Neither the manual nor the software offer any disadvantages or advantages of either mode.

From what I can observe, instant off has the advantage of being instantly off, while non-instant off has no advantages. Yet instant off is turned off by default. It seems there must be a reason why they choose this apparently inferior mode as defailt.

So my question is: are there any hidden disadvantages to instant off? Is it maybe bad for the lamp to be turned off instantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of a slower off is probably in the lifetime of the bulb.

Instant off will simply cut the power, and therefore allow the element to cool down very quickly. This has a risk of fast thermal shrinking and introducing micro-fractures in the element and as a result shortening the operational life-span of the bulb.

Turning off slowly will result in a controlled reduction in temperatures combined with moderate cooling and thus have less chance of thermal shock induced fractures.

Filament bulbs are, in general, most likely to die when turned on or off due to rapidly changing temperatures.

Comment: Absolutely. Seen this often in a decade of audio visual sales and service before I was issued a straitjacket and transferred to IT.

Comment: Interesting, I never considered that non-instant off would cool down slower, since the fan was running, but it totally makes sense. The lamp in my device is a gas filled tube lamp. I just had to replace it after 3/4 of the rated hours, so that's why I am asking about the instant off feature that I have been using so far. Thanks for the explanation! This sounds like something that should have been in the manual...

Comment: @Dakkaron It keeps the fan on along with the lamp (at a low setting) to effect a much more controlled and graceful cooling. I've seen some other posts online that also mention that it can benefit other components as well. Components like the LCD next to the bulb could also be suddenly hot (no fan, bulb takes a couple of seconds to cool) and rapidly cool in a similar way and so reduce their lifespan as well. It does feel like the sort of thing that should be mentioned when enabling the instant-off option, but then again they *want* you to be buying replacement bulbs and parts.